# How can I get the image inside of an element to adjust to the size of the div its contained in without setting it as a background image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Basically, I am envisioning a page which opens an image inside of an element which stretches the height of the screen and is masked within that height and the set width of the element. But I want to be able to continue scrolling after the fact.

Imagine a site divided into thirds maybe and only the middle third will be scrolled through. When you open the site, there is an image inside of the middle third. As you change the size of your window, the image properly adapts, but once you settle, you are able to begin scrolling through the middle portion of the site revealing text and other images underneath it.

For anyone interested in looking at the code I am working on, I will provide a codepen link. The aim is for the spine and book class to have heights fixed to the height of the screen. The spine won't scroll, but the book class will. I just want the image which appears at the top of the book class to appear as tall as the screen so that it is all you see before you begin scrolling through it.

https://codepen.io/brxtn/project/editor/XWRPzL

```
<div class="book">
    <div class="cover1">
      <img src="https://d2w9rnfcy7mm78.cloudfront.net/1004368/large_545c7a06dbaea4e0c1ccb78445041d39.jpg?1493861704?bc=1">

    </div>
```

```
.book{
    background: #000000;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 730px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
     border-left:none;
    background-color: white;
    }

img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way for setting explicitly your images in the html and use a property like background without attatching the image into an explicit class you can do the following

```css
.container {
  height: 450px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.cover-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.contain-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://d2w9rnfcy7mm78.cloudfront.net/1004368/large_545c7a06dbaea4e0c1ccb78445041d39.jpg?1493861704?bc=1" alt="" class="cover-image">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://d2w9rnfcy7mm78.cloudfront.net/1004368/large_545c7a06dbaea4e0c1ccb78445041d39.jpg?1493861704?bc=1" alt="" class="contain-image">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With this strategy you can have either the `cover` or the `contain` property of what you usually have while using background, this also allows you to keep your images responsive and keep the aspect ratio.

I Hope this helps somehow :)